# How to remove a Javascript external file with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working with a CMS and I am having an issue trying to remove some files so I am going to do it with Javascript.

I have this in the html:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/res/js/libs/moment.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/res/js/libs/moment-timezone.js"></script>
```

And I want to remove those files with Javascript, what's the best way to do that?

Comment: No. Remove them in your CMS template or settings. JS is the wrong tool. By the time you could remove them, it's already too late.

Answer (score 0):

Remove it either from html or if you don't have control over html, remove this 2 files from physical location or replace it with blank js files.....